# Array of Objects from Firestore returns nil in Swift even though it's not Empty?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
private func loadUserLearntChants() {
    Task {
        do {
            try await profileViewModel.loadCurrentUser()
            if let userId = profileViewModel.user?.userId {
                let user = try await userManager.getUser(userId: userId)
                if let learntChants = user.learntChants {
                    learntChantIds = learntChants
                }
                print(user)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

When I print user it says learntChants is nil

Array of Objects (learntChants) is returning nil:

[image: Array of Objects (learntChants) is returning nil]

Screenshot from Firestore showing that learnt_chants isn't empty:

[image: Screenshot from Firestore showing that learnt_chants isn't empty]

I read [Unpacking Firestore array with objects to a model in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67558899/unpacking-firestore-array-with-objects-to-a-model-in-swift), which said that you need to cast it to key-value type (Dictionary) first, then map it to LearntChant object

I tried this but it still didn't return anything

```
private func loadUserLearntChants() {
    Task {
        do {
            try await profileViewModel.loadCurrentUser()
            if let userId = profileViewModel.user?.userId {
                let user = try await userManager.getUser(userId: userId)
                if let learntChants = user.learntChants as? [[String: Any]] {
                    let learntChantObjects = learntChants.map { learntChant in
                        let chant = LearntChant(chantId: learntChants["chantId"] as? String ?? "none", voteType: learntChants["voteType"] as? String ?? "none")
                        return chant
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does an actor named profileViewModel come from?

Comment: Nothing is being done with `learntChantObjects`? In other words, the `.map` maps and creates a bunch of objects, and then adds them to `let learntChantObjects` but then `learntChantObjects' silently goes out of scope.

Comment: Also, the Firestore code is missing from the question so you should verify that you're actually reading objects from Firebase. There are a number of other places where the code could be failing so some additional troubleshooting would be a good idea (step through your code!). Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)